# How to find files that contain a string in its content OR the path?

Tags: linux, find, grep, busybox

Find and grep does not work afaik because I need to create a list of files that satisfy EITHER requirement, not both. I assume this requires more than a one-liner. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with the following command:

```
comm  -3 <(find path -name '*string*' | sort) \
         <( grep -r 'string' path | sed s=^=./= | sort)
```

You might need to change the `sed` part to make the paths reported by `find` and `grep` compatible. The `-3` switch to `comm` suppresses printing the files that appear in both the lists.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Unfortunately, comm is not available in my version of Busybox. I know how to run each command, but how can I filter and combine and sort the results?